# logstash nginx pattern thows the result in _grokparsefailure

Tags: nginx, logstash

I have an nginx patteer which was successfully tested in grokcontructor but when adding it to logstash 1.5.3 the logs do end up with _grokparsefailure

Here is a sample of my access.log:

```
207.46.13.34 - - [14/Aug/2015:18:33:50 -0400] "GET /tag/dnssec/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1961 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "-"
```

and here is the nignx pattern:

```
NGUSERNAME [a-zA-Z\.\@\-\+_%]+
NGUSER %{NGUSERNAME}
NGINXACCESS %{IPORHOST:clientip} %{NGUSER:indent} %{NGUSER:agent} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}] "%{WORD:verb} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}" %{NUMBER:answer} %{NUMBER:byte} "%{URI:referrer}" %{QS:referee} %{QS:agent}
```

my logstash.conf look like this:

```
input {
        lumberjack {
                port => 5000
                type => "logs"
                ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/z0z0.tk.crt"
                ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/z0z0.tk.key"
        }
}
filter {
        if [type] == "nginx-access" {
                grok {
                        match => { "message" => "${NGINXACCESS}" }
                }
                geoip {
                        source => "clientip"
                        target => "geoip"
                        database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
                        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
                        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
                }
                mutate {
                        convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float" ]
                }
        }
}
output {
        stdout {
                codec => rubydebug
        }
        elasticsearch {
                host => "172.17.0.5"
                cluster => "clustername"
                flush_size => 2000
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Alain for your suggestion I have recreated the pattern but having it in /opt/logstash/pattern/nginx did not work so I moved it to the logstash.conf which works and it looks like this:

```
if [type] == "nginx-access" {
                grok {
                        match => { 'message' => '%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{NGUSER:indent} %{NGUSER:agent} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{URIPATHPARAM:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|)\" %{NUMBER:answer} (?:%{NUMBER:byte}|-) (?:\"(?:%{URI:referrer}|-))\" (?:%{QS:referree}) %{QS:agent}' }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to match "-" into the field `referrer` using the pattern `URI`.  Unfortunately, "-" is not a valid character in the URI pattern, which is expecting something like "http://..."

There are pattern examples that match a string or a hyphen (like part of the built-in COMMONAPACHELOG):

```
 (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-)
```

which you could adjust to your pattern.

Comment: I have change the "%{URI:referrer}" with %{QS:referrer} and I am still getting everything parsing ending up with _grokparsefailure

Comment: I have changed the pattern now it looks like `NGINXACCESS %{IPORHOST:clientip} %{NGUSER:indent} %{NGUSER:agent} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{URIPATHPARAM:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|)" %{NUMBER:answer} (?:%{NUMBER:byte}|-) (?:"(?:%{URI:referrer}|-)"|%{QS:referrer}) %{QS:agent}`, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: My old pattern compiled in grok debugger as well. Anyways after I put the pattern directly in the logstash.conf it started to work.